# Open multiple URLs in the one selenium ide test

Tags: firefox, selenium

I am looking to run the one test on multiple URLs using the selenium ide plugin for Firefox. My environment is load balanced, so I have the same website working on a number of servers. I will be testing internally, so I can access each server via their internal IP address (e.g. 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, etc.). the purpose of the test I do is to check that servers are synchronized, by confirming that UI elements are there.

Is there a selenium command that will allow me to open a URL (e.g. 192.168.1.1), run a set of UI checks, then open the next URL (e.g. 192.168.1.2), and run the same UI checks again?

I currently change the base URL before every test to achieve this, but if I could automate this entirely, it will save me a lot of time (I have lots of different servers to hit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with Selenium IDE. But you can generate code for various languages, the Selenium API in those languages do allow opening multiple, independent browser instances.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had a bad feeling this may have been the case. Unfortunately the organisation I work for only uses the ide, so it looks like ill be using my existing method.